# This Question is related to MS Access related Left Join

Tags: ms-access, mysql-workbench

currently, I am having an issue while **mapping two tables in access using left join method** but unfortunately, I am having an issue as it is **creating duplicates** and I am frustrated please help me

**CODE:-**

```
SELECT Master.[Sr No], Master.CRN, Master.MobileNumber, Test.Date, Test.Time, Test.[Final Disposition], Test.Status
FROM Master LEFT JOIN Test ON Master.MobileNumber = Test.Phone
GROUP BY Master.[Sr No], Master.CRN, Master.MobileNumber, Test.Date, Test.Time, Test.[Final Disposition], Test.Status
ORDER BY Master.[Sr No], Test.Date DESC , Test.Time;
```

Comment: JOIN issues with duplicates means you probably need to join on multiple columns, or one of the tables has a 1 to many relationship in terms of the fields (like ID's, timestamps etc etc). It should be easy to pinpoint your issue by picking a record that is duplicated, filtering by it, and selecting * from the join to see whats causing the issue

Comment: Yes i have master data of the customer in which we map the activity we did which is calling the customer so Test table have the duplicate entries as there is possibility of multiple tries made to the customer in order to reach them in Excel it easy use vlookup and get the value but while doing in MS access using left join method in output the master file is getting duplicated

Comment: Edit question to provide sample data as text tables.